# Why SQL inserts are slower in AWS Aurora Serverless than in AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

We had an AWS MySQL RDS t3.xlarge instance with 2000 IOPS. Also, I have a cron job written in java which inserts data in a table: it can insert up to 12M rows daily. Since AWS RDS cost is quite high we decided to migrate to AWS Aurora Serverless v1.

But what was surprising for us: the job executed on AWS RDS in ~3 hours but on Aurora Serverless it took ~16 hours.

According to my [searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692905/aws-rds-slow-insert), it is suggested to change parameter values: `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit (1 -> 0)` and `sync_binlog (1 -> 0)`. For Aurora Serverless you can modify `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` but `sync_binlog` - no. Probably that's why changing `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` didn't give any results.

Also, there is another [similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/236721/aws-aurora-queries-much-slower-in-sending-data-phase-than-rds-instance) with the same concerns.

My questions are:

- Why on Aurora Serverless the same job executes almost 3x times slower than on AWS RDS (Although, I understand that t3.xlarge instance with 2000 IOPS is quite powerful)?
- Is there a solution to accelerate Aurora Serverless inserts?